# Is there a way to add 1 to a variable using "+="?

Tags: javascript, var

I am trying to add a value to a variable using the += function. This is the code I am using:

```
function getAnswer() {
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementById('numone').value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementById('numtwo').value);
    var oper = document.getElementById('oper').value;
    var numberOfEquation = 0;
    numberOfEquation += 1;
    if (oper == '+') {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        var txt = document.createTextNode(num1+num2 + ' - Equation ' + numberOfEquation);
        p.appendChild(txt);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    } else if (oper == '-') {
        var p2 = document.createElement('p');
        var txt2 = document.createTextNode(num1-num2 + ' - Equation ' + numberOfEquation);
        p2.appendChild(txt2);
        document.body.appendChild(p2);
    }
    console.log('You did an equation!');
}
```

I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, and? What went right? What's the problem here? You can do `v++` or `++v` or `v += 1`, all of which will increment a variable. Are you looking to increment this each time you run the function? If so you can't use a local variable, you must declare `numberOfEquation` outside of the function.

Comment: You are declaring the variable then adding 1 to it, it will always be 1 here.

Comment: Just because you're not using spaces doesn't mean `num1+num2` is passed any differently than `num2 + ' - Equation '` - wrap your equation in parenthesises.

Comment: I guess you want to move `var numberOfEquation = 0;` out of the function

Comment: Just poor hoisting. Move the var out. Like apparently Jonas states seconds before my comment :D

Comment: @ChrisW. This has nothing to do with hoisting. It's just variable scope -- he's creating a new variable each time the function is called.

Comment: @Barmar right, how's that not hoisting? If the var sits outside of the method... Or is just verbiage semantics?

Comment: @chrisW hoisting would be `let a = 1; { console.log(a); let a = 2; }`

Comment: Ya you're right I'm using the verbiage incorrectly. Not a term I use often obviously, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a misunderstanding of how local variables work.

Local variable:

```
 function x() {
   var y = 0;
   ++y;
   return y;
 }

 x(); // => 1
 x(); // => 1
 x(); // => 1
```

This returns `1` each time since `var y` explicitly declares a *local variable*. It will only exist during the execution of that function. As soon as the function terminates that variable ceases to exist. When the function starts up again it makes a brand new one.

Here's a different approach with a persistent variable:

```
 var y = 0;

 function x() {
   ++y;
   return y;
 }

 x(); // => 1
 x(); // => 2
 x(); // => 3
```

This is because `y` exists *outside the scope* of the function. It lives as long as your program does.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it, and now it works perfectly.

Comment: To paraphrase YouTube: "Be sure to upvote and accept!"